# dygraphs doesn't work with maven

Tags: maven, dygraphs

I added dependency of dygraphs to pom.xml, but it doesn't work.
I tried both of the two below.
Should I add all the js files to my project?
Help me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
    <artifactId>dygraphs</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>dygraphs</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you encounter? It's pretty unclear what "does not work" to other readers. Explain your problem in greater detail, please.

Comment: Sorry. I used to use imported js files, but I can't draw any dygraphs only with the dygraphs dependency.